# Xamarin WebView - Can't Disable Double Click Event

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, webview

I'm trying to disable any double clicking functionality from happening, in this case, to disable the functionality of double clicking an instagram image to like it. I have tested some JavaScript as a chrome extension, and it gives me the results I am looking for, but when I bring it into a Xamarin WebView, it doesn't work. What's weird is that the injected JavaScript is being ran, because if I have an alert inside of it, it's displayed. It's just still liking the image on Instagram.

This is the JavaScript for the Chrome Extension

```
document.addEventListener("dblclick",handler,true);function handler(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); }
```

And this is the code for Xamarin

```
  string function = "document.addEventListener(\"dblclick\",handler,true);function handler(e){e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault();}";
  Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { webBrowser.Eval(function); });
```

UPDATE:
After some testing, I can confirm this is an issue only when running the mobile version of the site. I'm not sure if this has to do with how the events are triggered or something along this matter, but it is something with mobile only.

Answer (score 2):

I created a sample-page with just a webview to test your case:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.Page1" Appearing="Page1_OnAppearing">
    <WebView x:Name="TestWebView" />
</ContentPage>
```

And in the code behind I set static html with a button which shows an alert after double-clicking it:

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Set static html
    TestWebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
        Html = @"<html>
        <body>
        <button id='testbutton' style='font-size: 30px;'>Click me</button>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.getElementById('testbutton').addEventListener('dblclick', function (e) {
          alert('double clicked');
        });
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>"
    };
}
```

And in the OnAppearing event of the page I execute the javascript to prevent the double-click event-handler:

```
private void Page1_OnAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var script = "document.addEventListener('dblclick',handler,true);function handler(e) { e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); }";
    TestWebView.Eval(script);
}
```

After running this code, the double-click-alert still appears after double-clicking my test-button. This is because the javascript-eval runs to early. Or in other words: you have to give the webview a little more time to load the content, before executing the javascript:

```
private async void Page1_OnAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Just wait a little bit before calling eval
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    var script = "document.addEventListener('dblclick',handler,true);function handler(e) { e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); }";
    TestWebView.Eval(script);
}
```

And now, the alert no longer appears.

Let me know if this works in your case.

**Edit: Another approach**
Maybe the problem is caused by the implementation of the Instagram page. Another approach to disable double-click is to disable to whole events on the instagram-posts.

You can set following [css-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to disable this:

```
style="pointer-events:none;"
```

So you have to determine the xpath to the div-elements and set the style with javascript like this:

```
htmlElement.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events:none;");
```

I tested this on my browser (chrome debugger) and it worked. But I can not conclusively say if that works in your case via app.

Comment: Thank you for the help but this seems to have no effect in my case. Also, as a side note, I am not running the script at the time of page loading, it is triggered by a button in the Xaml, therefor the page should be well loaded by the time it is pressed. I am also wondering if it's possibly something to do with Instagrams webpage for mobile, maybe this could be causing some issue in my case.

Comment: I suspect this situation is caused by the implementation of the Instagram page. Maybe they use a different way to detect the double-click. I Iedited my answer with an alternative way. Can you check this?